# How to change an element in a modal after it was launched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I'm working on modifying a BigCommerce template and I want to change some text in the modal **After** it was launched.
I'm using jQuery to overcome these issues on the normal pages, but on the modal it doesn't work.
The next piece of code is used on 'ordinary' pages:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.TopMenu li:contains("or")').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(text.replace('or', 'maybe'));
        });
});
```

The next code *Doesn't* work for the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#ModalContainer").ready(function(){
            $('#fastCartNumItemsTxt').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(this).html(text.replace('items','stuff'));
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm trying to use:

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").on( "click", function() {
        $("#ModalContainer").ready(function(){
            $('#fastCartNumItemsTxt').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(this).html(text.replace('items','stuff'));
            });
        });
     });
```

Where ".ProductActionAdd a" represents the Add to Cart button which fires up the modal. Still doesn't work...

Any idea why?

Comment: `this` can be very tricky in JavaScript. it would be better to explicitly refer to what you want to modify.

Comment: How does it not work?  Is the `each` finding no items in `#fastCartNumItemsTxt`?

Comment: ID selector returns one element, why are you using `each`? Also `$("#ModalContainer").ready(function(){` doesn't make sense. It seems when the code is executed there is no element with ID of `ModalContainer`, is this true? `ready` method doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @undefined     
You are right about the fact that there's no such element. I know that I'm using the ready method in a wrong way, if you can correct me, that would be great!

Comment: If the modal script triggers an event or has a callback you can put the code in an event handler or a callback function.

Comment: @undefined 
any chance that you can show an example? I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: What modal plugin do you use?

Comment: I dont know (it's complicated to explain)

Comment: @undefined      
They are using fancybox. does that help?

Comment: @alexunder Yes, fancybox triggers many events that you can listen to, please read it's docs.

Comment: @undefined     
Mate, I know that, I'm saying the I'm having trouble understanding the docs. I understand the idea of how to do it, but my implementation sucks...\

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just putting this script inside of the modal content panel in Bigcommerce, if you're looking for fast cart you can just go inside `FastCartThickBoxContent.html`

Other than that you'll have to use the iModal callback, which I am not familiar with.